# keycloak openid single log out with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, logout, openid-connect, keycloak

I'm trying to implement a single log out in my spring boot applications using keycloak and openid.

I already setup keycloak 3.4.3 with sprint boot 1.5.3 and spring security adapter (documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter)), algo using tomcat adapter (documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_tomcat_adapter) ). Everything works fine until I try to log out from all my sessions.

I have tried:

1) On keycloak administration console ui: logout all sessions
 result: it does clean all sessions from keycloak, but not the browser ones in my client applications. So I keep logged in until i delete them manually.

2) Using `HttpServletRequest.logout()` and `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri` (documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#logout)), only logs out from the current client and not as a SLO

I'm not sure if OpenID supports SLO and I cannot find any reliable documentation about it.

¿Is there a way to implement Single log out using OpenID and Spring boot?

Comment: OpenId Connect is specified in a way that, if properly implemented, clients check the identity provider regularly to refresh the access token. If your access tokens are relatively short-lived, a log out in the linked session would cause them not to be refreshed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a proper implementation?,  at least for the log out process. The keycloak documentation isn't that explicit in this topic

Comment: I don't have any KC instance available to test, but could you try if calling the `/sso/logout` endpoint in your application triggers a Single Sign Out? The adapter should take care of it.  Ex. `http://myapplication/sso/logout`

Comment: I set up the Admin URL with http://myapplication/sso/logout and it did the work, thanks!

Comment: @dgr018, How did you achieve 'logout'? When I tried `http://myapplication/sso/logout` it didn't work. Responded me with `404`.

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB, did you create the request mapping for "/logout" in your controller? I also extended a class from `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you can find an example here [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak#2-configuration-class). Also, in the configure method, I have this 
`super.configure(http);
  http
  .logout()
     .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/sso/logout")) and() ...`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following to log out

```
   @GetMapping(path = "/logout")
   public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
      request.logout();
      return "/";
   }
```

http

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: This invalidates the Spring session and does nothing else. However, since the SSO session is not terminated you will automatically be logged in again as soon as you navigate to another page.

Comment: This invalidates spring and keycloak session, because redirect me to keycloak login., (spring-boot 2.3.3, keycloak-spring-boot-starter 11.0.1).

Comment: I can confirm @Ciri comment. There is no logout for the keycloak session. Only the Spring is invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#logout) `HttpServletRequest.logout()` should work but it does not work. By mistake or some other reasons, this way makes logout only for web container session but not for keycloak session. It requires some additional work.

```
for keycloak-spring-boot-starter:17.0.1
```

```
    /**
     * Makes SSO Logout.
     * This endpoint has to be private. Otherwise there will be no token to send logout to KeyCloak.
     *
     * @param request the request
     * @return redirect to logout page
     * @throws ServletException if tomcat session logout throws exception
     */
    @GetMapping(path = "/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        keycloakSessionLogout(request);
        tomcatSessionLogout(request);
        return "redirect:/public/logout.html";
    }

    private void keycloakSessionLogout(HttpServletRequest request){
        RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext c = getKeycloakSecurityContext(request);
        KeycloakDeployment d = c.getDeployment();
        c.logout(d);
    }

    private void tomcatSessionLogout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
         request.logout();
    }

    private RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext getKeycloakSecurityContext(HttpServletRequest request){
        return (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment "This endpoint has to be private...." That was the one (hopefully last) detail I was missing!